# Explicit template instantiation of templated friend of templated class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, friend, explicit-instantiation

I have a main class `MainClass` whose private member variables should be visible to a friend class `FriendClass`.
Both are templated by an `int` called `dim`, and they both have their respective header and source files (and are thus in different translation units).
Since `MainClass` doesn't really depend on `FriendClass` (and to avoid circular dependency) I forward declare `FriendClass` as a template class when doing the friend declaration in `MainClass`.
Additionally, at the end of the source files I explicitly instantiate both classes for `dim = 2` and `dim = 3`.
However, when I compile I get an error that the private member variable of `MainClass` is private within this context when I try to use it in a method of `FriendClass`.
I suspect this has something to do with the fact that a particular instantiation of `FriendClass` does not recognize that the corresponding instantiation of `MainClass` has declared it a friend, but I'm not sure how to fix the problem.
Code:

```cpp
// MainClass.hpp
#ifndef MAIN_CLASS_HPP
#define MAIN_CLASS_HPP

template <int dim>
class MainClass
{
public:
    MainClass(){};
private:
    
    template <int friend_dim>
    class FriendClass;
    
    friend class FriendClass<dim>;
    
    double private_member = 3.0;
};

#endif
```

```cpp
// MainClass.cpp
#include "MainClass.hpp"

template class MainClass<2>;
template class MainClass<3>;
```

```cpp
// FriendClass.hpp
#ifndef FRIEND_CLASS_CPP
#define FRIEND_CLASS_CPP

#include "MainClass.hpp"

template <int dim>
class FriendClass
{
public:
    FriendClass(){};
    
    void print_main_class(MainClass<dim> &main_class);
};

#endif
```

```cpp
// FriendClass.cpp
#include "FriendClass.hpp"

#include <iostream>

template <int dim>
void FriendClass<dim>::print_main_class(MainClass<dim> &main_class)
{
    std::cout << main_class.private_member << std::endl;
}

template class FriendClass<2>;
template class FriendClass<3>;
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "MainClass.hpp"
#include "FriendClass.hpp"

int main()
{
    const int dim = 2;
    MainClass<dim> main_class;
    FriendClass<dim> friend_class;
    
    friend_class.print_main_class(main_class);

    return 0;
}
```

Code available to compile live at [onlinegdb.com](https://onlinegdb.com/Kn3rji58o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared two different class templates both named `FriendClass`.  Probably unintentionally.

One is the global `FriendClass` and the other is `MainClass::FriendClass`.

You can fix this by forward declaring your class template in the namespace it exists in.

```
// MainClass.hpp
#ifndef MAIN_CLASS_HPP
#define MAIN_CLASS_HPP

template <int>
class FriendClass;

template <int dim>
class MainClass
{
public:
    MainClass(){};
private:
    
    friend FriendClass<dim>;
//  Now the global FriendClass is a friend.
    
    double private_member = 3.0;
};

#endif
```

Comment: One follow-up: is forward-declaring the `FriendClass` in the `MainClass` header file considered polluting the global namespace? And if so, is there a nice way to avoid that?

Comment: @LucasMyers I don't imagine that many would consider a forward declaration of something that is already in the global namespace as "polluting the global namespace".  It does not change what is in the global namespace.